# Find a continuous map $f(x_i)=t_i$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space and $\mathbb{T}$ the circle group. If $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ and $t_1,...,t_n\in \mathbb{T}$ then there exists a continuous map $f:X\to \mathbb{T}$ such that $f(x_i)=t_i$ for each $i$.

How can I prove this? By the way, maybe this result is some more general, I think we can put $Y$ any topological space instead of $\mathbb{T} $ or something like that.

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since a Tychonoff space is completely regular and finite sets are closed, for each $j$ there is $g_j: X \to \mathbb R$ such that 
$g_j(x_j) =  1$ and $g_j(x_k) = 0$ for $k \ne j$.  Consider $\exp(i \sum_j c_j g_j)$ for suitable $c_j$.

You can't generalize this too far: in particular it doesn't work if $X$ is connected and $Y$ is not.

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert.